# Div side by side spacing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have div's side by side using flexbox but there is some unwanted behavior.

Is there anyway to have box 4 and box 5 both centered? Or have box 5 go in the middle of the second row?

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/1sgrqu25/

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Box 1</div>
  <div class="child">Box 2</div>
  <div class="child">Box 3</div>
  <div class="child">Box 4</div>
  <div class="child">Box 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're setting a width of 30% on these divs, you could use `justify-content: flex-start;` or `justify-content: center;` to do this. I also changed `margin-bottom: 10px` to `margin: 10px` to maintain the spacing.

https://jsfiddle.net/e24d9wcz/

Comment: I like this solution the best because it provides for both aligning left and aligning right. Thank you!

Comment: Is there anyway to use `justify-content: flex-start;` but center all the boxes towards the center? Because of the `margin: 10px`, is there anyway to dynamically center all boxes with space between them and then left align the left row?

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something as simple as `justify-content: space-around`:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Box 1</div>
  <div class="child">Box 2</div>
  <div class="child">Box 3</div>
  <div class="child">Box 4</div>
  <div class="child">Box 5</div>
</div>
```

Another option is to give the fourth and fifth items a margin of auto on their outer sides:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 30%;
}

.child:nth-child(4){
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right:10px;
}

.child:nth-child(5){
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Box 1</div>
  <div class="child">Box 2</div>
  <div class="child">Box 3</div>
  <div class="child">Box 4</div>
  <div class="child">Box 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the width of the elements, and the width of the gaps are fixed, you can use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout):

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px 3.3%;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Box 1</div>
  <div class="child">Box 2</div>
  <div class="child">Box 3</div>
  <div class="child">Box 4</div>
  <div class="child">Box 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the `justify-content` of `.parent` into `center`.

Don't forget to adjust the gap between each `.child` division by using `margin-right`.

Remove the 3rd divided position's `.child` `margin-right` of each row to make entire layout looks tidy.

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  margin-right:calc(10% / 3); /*Add gap between each child*/
}

.parent>.child:nth-child(3n){
  margin-right:0px; /*remove gap last child of each row*/
}
```